# clearing entry text with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So i'm having trouble with deleting text that is entered by the user any help? This is some of the code...

```
menubar = Menu(mGui)


filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command = mNew)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command = mOpen)
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command = mQuit)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu=filemenu)

#Edit bar condtruction
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
editmenu.add_command(label="Clear Text", command = mClear)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "Edit", menu=editmenu)
```

here is the things explaining the mQuit and stuff

```
def mhello():
    mtext = ment.get()
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui, text = mtext).pack()
    return
def mNew():
    filemenu.add_command(label="New")
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    return
def mClear():
    delete(first, last=None)
```

plz help me clear the text, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that `ment` refers to a tkinter entry widget, you would use `ment.delete(0,"end").